# Unable to load html video tag in wxHtmlWindow?

Tags: c++, user-interface, html5-video, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I am trying to set html page in `wxHtmlWindow`. It is loading all the basic tags except html video tag.

Note: My HTML file with the same video tag is working fine (Video is playing).

```
    html = new wxHtmlWindow(this);
    html -> SetRelatedFrame(this, _("wxHTML Demo: '%s'"));
#if wxUSE_STATUSBAR
    html -> SetRelatedStatusBar(1);
#endif // wxUSE_STATUSBAR
    
    html->SetPage("<html><head><title>File System Example</title>"
        "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='memory:test.css'>"
        "</head><body><h1>Page 2</h1>"
        "<p><a href='memory:page1.htm'>Page 1</a> was better.</p>"
        "<video width='700px' controls> <source src='myvideo.mp4' type='video/mp4' /></body></html>");
```

Comment: The html is missing `</video>` closing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It supports only a limited set of tags, and was not even intended to cover them all.

But, *wxHtmlWindow supports [tag handlers](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_html.html#overview_html_handlers). This means that you can easily extend wxHtml library with new, unsupported tags.*